# Do I need to pay taxes in India?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, dtaa, inr-indian-rupee

I am working on a two months of independent In-house corporate photographer with a US company. I came here on `Business Visa` and I should had to open  local bank account because the company is only giving me corporate checks. I had two corporate checks and deposited back them to my local bank account. I will be going back to India in next month and need to transfer all the money to my Indian bank account from US bank account. Do I need to pay taxes in India in this scenario?

As per my knowledge I should have to because till you are holding Indian citizenship you have to pay taxes in India whether your company is paying directly income to your Indian bank account or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to pay taxes in India in this scenario?

For India tax purposes, you would still qualify as "Resident Indian". As a resident Indian you have to pay taxes on Global income. It is not relevant whether you transfer the money back to India to keep in US. The income is generated and taxable.

Depending on your contract, presumably you are working as a free lance; certain expenses are allowed to be deducted from your income, for example if you purchase equipment to help carry out the work, stay / entertainment costs, etc.

Consult a professional CA who should be able to guide you on what is eligible and what is not. The balance along with your other income will be taxed as per tax brackets.

There is exemption for certain category of workers, mostly in entertainment industry where such income is not taxable. This does not apply to your case.